# How do you actually calculate numbers like $2^{\pi}$ or $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}160]{2}$

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function

My question is very simple, but I started to wonder how does one calculate numbers like $2^{\pi}$ or $\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}160]{2}$?

For example I know that:

$$2^{3/2} = \sqrt{2^3}=\sqrt{8}\approx2.83,$$

which is easy to calculate. But what about the cases I gave as an example? How would one go about and calculate those numbers using nothing else but a pencil and paper without calculator allowed?

Would we use some kind of series here to approximate these numbers?

It is also a bit unclear to me what $2^{\pi}$ means. For example to me, $2^3$ means in words: "Multiply number $2$ three times by itself", so multiplying $2$ by $\pi$ times by itself feels a bit weird when you're used to having integers in the exponent.

Thank you for any help and clarifications :)

Comment: Not a complete answer, but for real numbers with $u > 0$, and with $\log$ denoting the natural logarithm, one defines $u^{v} = e^{v \log u}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a>0$.

1) One starts defining $a^n$ for $n$ integer:
$$
a^0:=1,\quad a^{n+1}:=a\cdot a^n.
$$
2) Then one defines $y=a^{1/n}$ as the unique positive solution of $y^n=a$.

3) Next
$$
a^{m/n}=\left(a^{1/n}\right)^m,
$$
obtaining a general definition of power with rational exponent.

4) Finally, for any $x\in \mathbb R$, one can find $q_i=m_i/n_i\in \mathbb Q$ such that $q_i\to x$. Therefore one defines
$$
a^x=\lim_ia^{q_i}.
$$
This is *well defined* because one can prove that the result is independent of the approximating sequence (continuity) i.e.
$$
\lim_iq_i=\lim_iq'_i\Rightarrow \lim_ia^{q_i}=\lim_ia^{q'_i}
$$
(This proof is not difficult, being the exponential monotone).

Comment: Thank you for your help @guestDiego. So the answer is: "We use approximations to calculate these numbers numerically"?

Comment: In other words with pencil and paper, you start to break the $2^{\pi}$ into "smaller and smaller pieces" which are easier to calculate?

Comment: @ jjepsuomi Yes: the exponetial with real exponent is basically an extension by continuity. One can find different ways, for example define directly $e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i/i!$. However you see that this is a definition based on infinite deries, so basically it is a limit.

Comment: @jjepsuomi as for $2^\pi$, you calculate $2^3$, $2^{31/10}$, $2^{314/100}$, $2^{3141/1000}$ etc. This is of course a way in principle. It does not mean that it is efficient!

Comment: Excellent, this covers my question. 10 points ;D Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

High school example. The binomial theorem.

$$(1+x)^n=1+nx + \frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2!}+\frac{n(n-1)x^3}{3!}+\ldots$$
here, $x=1$ and $n=\pi$ thus
\begin{align}
(1+1)^\pi &= 1 + \pi.1 + \frac{\pi(\pi-1)}{2}.1^2+\ldots \\
&= 1+ \pi + \frac{\pi^2-\pi}{2}+\ldots \\
&= 1+\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{2}\\
&\approx 1 + \frac{3}{2}+\frac{9}{2}\\
&= 7
\end{align}
admittedly a very very crude approximation.

Comment: Thank you @Bacon for you help! Appreciate your effort much!

Comment: $2^\pi \geq 2^3 = 8$, so your approximation is somewhat useless. Anyway, the second line of the expansion of $(1+1)^\pi$ looks mysterious. Where's the ${1 \over 2}$?

Comment: @lisyarus I admitted it was a crude approximation, but I was concentrating on *methods* for evaluating numbers *like* $2^\pi$. I thank you for spotting my erratum, it is now fixed.

Comment: @Bacon Sure, and this is a really nice method. I would just add a few terms to make it more reasonable.

Comment: @lisyarus Yes, the flaw in my method here is that In the final numerical substitution I assume that $\pi = 3$ which renders the terms $\mathscr{O}(3)$ onwards zero

Comment: You should use this series only after some reductions, for instance $$2^\pi=8/(1-\frac12)^{\pi-3}.$$

Comment: Using your approach, you should get $2^\pi=\frac{6+ \pi(5 +\pi ^2)}{6} $ Using $\pi\approx 3$ and $\pi^2\approx 10$ and the result would be $\approx \frac{51}6=8.5$. Using $\pi\approx \frac{22}7$, the result would be  $\frac{3016}{343}\approx 8.793$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Nice, I did wonder about not being so absolute by choosing $\pi=3$ but as you write, approximately would work better. Many thanks for adding a robustness to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$2^\pi=2^3\times 2^{\pi-3}=8\times 2^{\pi-3}=8e^{(\pi-3)\log(2)}$$ Now, let us use the truncated series $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and use $(\pi-3)\log(2)\approx 0.0981445\approx \frac 1{10}$. So $$e^{(\pi-3)\log(2)}\approx 1+\frac 1{10}+\frac 1{200}+\frac 1{6000}=\frac{6631}{6000}$$ So, $$2^\pi\approx \frac{8 \times 6631}{6000}=\frac{6631}{750}\approx 8.84133$$ while the "exact" value should be $8.82498$.

For sure, this implies that you know the value of $\pi$ and the value of $\log(2)$.

For the second one $$\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}160]{2}=e^{\frac{\log(2)}{160}}\approx e^{\frac{43}{1000}}$$ and use again the development of $e^x$ for two terms (I suppose).

Answer (score 2):

How I would think about $2^{\pi}$ is the following:

Consider an infinite sequence $(a_{0},a_{1},a_{2}\ldots)$ such that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}=\pi$$
Then
$$2^{\pi}=2^{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}}=2^{a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots}=2^{a_{0}}2^{a_{1}}2^{a_{2}}\cdots$$
Now $2^{\pi}$ can be represented as a infinite product:
$$2^{\pi}=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{a_{n}}$$
There are infinite number of equations for $a_{n}$ but here's a link for a few, if you want to know them.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html